# Slice function in python

Tags: python

I'm wondering how to slice only the USERNAMES from a text file, I know the basic slicing but with the exact index only like dates and time.

The file looks like this

```
username: kara_v password: 123456 dept: accounting vlan: 5
username: carla_s password: 654321 dept: accounting vlan: 5
username: mary_j password: 345645 dept: accounting vlan: 5
username: leny_k  password: 568890 dept: accounting vlan: 5
username: raul_t  password: abscdf dept: production1 vlan: 6
username: paul_s  password: hgytt dept: production1 vlan: 6
username: steph_j  password: gfrrss dept: production1 vlan: 6
username: sally_g  password: appookk dept: production1 vlan: 6
username: maan_h  password: 123rfg dept: branch1 vlan: 11
username: ricky_m password: 678yuh dept: branch1 vlan: 11
username: zola_b  password: gghh12 dept: branch1 vlan: 11
username: jeremy_n password: fgh347 dept: branch1 vlan: 11
```

Comment: Use `split()` to split each line into a list of words. Then use a list index to get the usernames. No slicing needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open the file, scan all the lines for the patter `username: <some_string>` this little regex can do that:

note: usernames.txt below is the same as the lines you've posted above.

```
import re

usernames = None

with open('usernames.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    usernames = re.findall(r'username: (.*?)[\s]', lines)

print(usernames)
```

1. `re.findall` finds all occurrences of the string match `username:`
2. `(.*?)` matches any character except a newline
3. `[\s]` escapes on any whitespace character
4. This prints a list of all the usernames

```
['kara_v', 'carla_s', 'mary_j', 'leny_k', 'raul_t', 'paul_s', 'steph_j', 'sally_g', 'maan_h', 'ricky_m', 'zola_b', 'jeremy_n']
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work? considering text file name is **info.txt**

modified based on comment

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f: 
    lines = f.readlines()
    users = list(map(lambda x: x.split()[1],lines))
    print(users)
```

Comment: This one works, I'll try to sort it alphabetically, thank you!

Comment: you can sort it with `users.sort()`

Answer (score -1):

One more approach with sed (not thoroughly tested)

```
sed 's/ password.*$//;s/username: //' inputfile
```

Comment: I haven't tried this one since i don't know where to put it, anyways, thank you!

Comment: sed is a stream editor tool, you can try that on a command line

Comment: This works, but the questioner asked how to solve their problem in Python, not using Unix command line tools like `sed`